# Class ZipArchive(), some errors with function

Tags: php

I'm looking for a mistake in my code for 2 days now :

```
<?php

echo $_FILES['import']['name']; ?> <br/> <?php
echo $_FILES['import']['type']; ?> <br/> <?php
echo $_FILES['import']['size']; ?> <br/> <?php
echo $_FILES['import']['tmp_name']; ?> <br/> <?php
echo $_FILES['import']['error'];

if ($_FILES['import']['error'] > 0) {
    echo "Erreur lors du transfert";
}  
else  {
    echo "Transfert Ok" ;?> <br/> <?php

    $nom = $_FILES['import']['name'];
    $localisation = $_FILES['import']['tmp_name'];

    echo $nom; ?> <br/> <?php
    echo $localisation; ?> <br/> <?php

    $zip = new ZipArchive();

    $res = $zip->open($localisation."/".$nom);
//  echo $res;
    if($res === TRUE)   {
        echo 'ok';
    }
    else {
        echo 'erreur';
    }
}
?>
```

My problem is with the `ZipArchive` class. As for me, `open()` and `extractTo()` functions don't work.

This code is always edited to find a solution. Now i'm trying to "open", it doesn't work.
I don't know why. As for me, the path is not correct, but when I see the path (using `echo $localisation."/".$nom`), it actually is.

Does any one have a solution or an advice for a debutant developper ?

Comment: any error log that you can add to the question? it will be helpful for others to give a solution.

Comment: I have no errors at this moment, just this code doesn't "enter" in the if condition. (if($res === TRUE)   {
        echo 'ok';
    }). I'm trying the solution under this post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason perhaps that your function does not work might be the line `$res = $zip->open($localisation."/".$nom);` - this would result in a string such as `/tmp/a23mt.tmp/somefile.zip` which would be wrong. Perhaps the following might help though you might wish to designate a particular folder path to save uploaded files to rather than the current working directory of the script.

```
/* for convenience, create an object representation of the uploaded file */
$file=(object)$_FILES['import'];
/* assign variables */
$name=$file->name;
$type=$file->type;
$size=$file->size;
$tmp=$file->tmp_name;
$error=$file->error;



if( $error==UPLOAD_ERR_OK ){
    if( is_uploaded_file( $tmp ) ){

        /* need to store the file somewhere */
        $target = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $name;

        /* move the uploaded file before processing */
        $result = move_uploaded_file( $tmp, $target );

        /* was the file moved successfully? */
        if( file_exists( $target ) ){
            clearstatcache();

            /* do stuff - zip */
            $zip = new ZipArchive();
            $result = $zip->open( $target );

            echo $result ? 'ok' : 'erreur';
        } else {
            echo "Error moving/saving file!";
        }

    } else {
        echo "Error! Not an uploaded file...attempted hack!"
    }
} else {
    echo "Erreur lors du transfert!"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, it's works ! Now, i'm trying to extract my file, thanks a lot.